# Bootstrap 3 / 4, container in container-fluid or row without columns. Graphic example

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, containers

I need a simple schema like this in picture:

[image]

This is a try: http://plnkr.co/edit/6v6C4PZCGfvH9FavNai0?p=preview without success.

How to accomplish this?

I need what is in picture. Exactly.

In xs mode I disable many things. My problem is in desktop mode.

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background:red">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="d-inline-block" style="background-color:blue">
          <div class="container">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background:white">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-inline-block" style="background-color:yellow; float:right">
          <span class="d-inline-block" style="background:white; padding: 20px">User box</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no much sense develop in bootstrap without grid/colmuns orientantion. You can set a fixed width for you inner element "user box".

Try this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.3" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.3" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
    <script data-require="bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.3" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.3" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background:red">
      <div class="row">
        
          <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-9">
              <nav class="navbar navbar-light" style="background:white">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-xs-right">
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Right</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3" style="background-color:yellow; float:right">
              <span class="d-inline-block" style="background:white; padding: 20px">User box</span>
            </div>
         </div>  
     </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Dear @Yuri Ramos, this is not what I need. I need the red color just from the left of the screen (wher container-fluid start) to the right of the first column (where menu end). Than column can be fluid (I can also not use the "container" class for the first column) and the second column must be fluid (and not col-md-3) because the content may change a lot from page to page. I cannot say if is enough col-md-3, or 2 or 1, and I don't want the right margin of that box. It's more clear now?

Comment: look at my picture. I need the blue (with or without "container" ability) just from left to the right of menu. And to the right of the container-fluid I need just the space for the green box (with small padding and margin of course).